# Attribute not found for closure

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, boto3, zappa

### Code

```
    def zappa_async(func):
        print('here')
        @wraps(func)
        @task(capture_response=True)
        def func_wrap_async(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        def func_wrap_async_response_id(*args, **kwargs):
            return func_wrap_async(*args, **kwargs).response_id

        return func_wrap_async_response_id
```

### Expected Behavior

Take a function and return a new function that is asynchronous and returns its response id

### Actual Behavior

lambda throws module 'rap_stats.MapReduce' has no attribute 'func_wrap_async': AttributeError

### Update

It works when I remove '@task' and '.response_id' but I need these in order for it to properly function asynchronously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [README](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa#responses) says:

> To capture responses, you must configure a `async_response_table` in `zappa_settings`.

This needs to be done.